# How to plot data against specific dates on the x-axis using matplotlib

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I have a dataset consisting of date-value pairs. I want to plot them in a bar graph with the specific dates in the x-axis.

My problem is that `matplotlib` distributes the `xticks` over the entire date range; and also plots the data using points.

The dates are all `datetime` objects. Here's a sample of the dataset:

```
data = [(DT.datetime.strptime('2010-02-05', "%Y-%m-%d"), 123),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-02-19', "%Y-%m-%d"), 678),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-03-05', "%Y-%m-%d"), 987),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-03-19', "%Y-%m-%d"), 345)]
```

Here is a runnable code sample using `pyplot`

```
import datetime as DT
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = [(DT.datetime.strptime('2010-02-05', "%Y-%m-%d"), 123),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-02-19', "%Y-%m-%d"), 678),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-03-05', "%Y-%m-%d"), 987),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-03-19', "%Y-%m-%d"), 345)]

x = [date for (date, value) in data]
y = [value for (date, value) in data]

fig = plt.figure()

graph = fig.add_subplot(111)
graph.plot_date(x,y)

plt.show()
```

**QUESTION SUMMARY:**
My situation is more like I have an `Axes` instance ready (referenced by `graph` in the code above) and I want to do the following:

1. Make the `xticks` correspond to the exact date values. I have heard of `matplotlib.dates.DateLocator` but I have no idea how create one and then associate it with a specific `Axes` object.
2. Get tighter control over the type of graph being used (bar, line, points, etc.)

Comment: Just a tip: since your question really is purely about matplotlib and doesn't have anything specific to wxWidgets, it'd might make things easier if you alter your example to use the functions from `matplotlib.pyplot` and leave the wx stuff out of it.

Comment: @David: Fixed. Thanks, I realized there might be more people who can read `matplotlib` + `pyplot` better than `matplotlib` + `wx`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you're doing is simple enough that it's easiest to just using plot, rather than plot_date. plot_date is great for more complex cases, but setting up what you need can be easily accomplished without it.

e.g., Based on your example above:

```
import datetime as DT
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

data = [(DT.datetime.strptime('2010-02-05', "%Y-%m-%d"), 123),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-02-19', "%Y-%m-%d"), 678),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-03-05', "%Y-%m-%d"), 987),
        (DT.datetime.strptime('2010-03-19', "%Y-%m-%d"), 345)]

x = [date2num(date) for (date, value) in data]
y = [value for (date, value) in data]

fig = plt.figure()

graph = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Plot the data as a red line with round markers
graph.plot(x,y,'r-o')

# Set the xtick locations to correspond to just the dates you entered.
graph.set_xticks(x)

# Set the xtick labels to correspond to just the dates you entered.
graph.set_xticklabels(
        [date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for (date, value) in data]
        )

plt.show()
```

If you'd prefer a bar plot, just use [`plt.bar()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.bar).  To understand how to set the line and marker styles, see [`plt.plot()`](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)
[Plot with date labels at marker locations http://www.geology.wisc.edu/~jkington/matplotlib_date_labels.png](http://www.geology.wisc.edu/~jkington/matplotlib_date_labels.png)