# How to make date tick marks more precise in matplotlib?

Tags: python, date, numpy, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib to chart data with `datetime.date` as the x-axis.

Currently the graph has tick marks of the month and year in a certain range.  As this range is too wide, the actual point for the price can't even be seen.

I want my matplotlib chart to plot x tick marks either:

- for every date that is retrieved from the table, or
- within a small enough range (e.g. 30 days within a month) so the price of the ticket on each of the days can be seen.

How can this be done?

I tried solutions from SO questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608788/changing-the-tick-frequency-on-x-or-y-axis-in-matplotlib) but they aren't working, probably because the dates from the table aren't of type float.

Here's an image of the chart:

[image]

Comment: The answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486121/how-to-plot-data-against-specific-dates-on-the-x-axis-using-matplotlib?rq=1) should work for you.

Comment: @cphlewis The solution posted there enabled me to plot points for each date on the x-axis, but the problem is that I only have points for the entire year of 2015. For some reason, the `datetime.date` type  can't be parsed and converted into a float that can be plotted. Should I convert the table column or is there another solution? I have the statement `import matplotlib.dates as dateToNum` and have `xs = [dateToNum.datestr2num(x[0]) for x in coordinateList]` to parse the query results.

Comment: I don't get your difficulty. If you made a complete runnable example like the linked one -- with the input data in the format you have, and an explanation of how the output plot differs from what you want -- it might be clearer.

Comment: @cphlewis nevermind I fixed the problem