# Plot Frequency of Dates

Tags: python, date, matplotlib

I have a file with a list of dates, formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD". The data is well-structured, so I don't need to be concerned with outliers. I'm using a `defaultdict` to get the count of occurrences of each date. For example, the dictionary may look like:

```
2015-01-01 : 5
2015-01-15 : 3
2015-02-03 : 4
2015-02-04 : 2
```

I'd like to plot the counts as a histogram, where the spacing along the x-axis is commensurate with the dates. If there is a large gap between dates, I would like the bars to be spaced accordingly. Is this possible?

I've found a very similar question, [How to plot data against specific dates on the x-axis using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486121/how-to-plot-data-against-specific-dates-on-the-x-axis-using-matplotlib?rq=1), but this uses a line graph instead of bars, like a histogram.

Comment: Do you mean *histogram* or *barplot* they're two different things.

Comment: Histogram. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python pandas: plot histogram of dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365467/python-pandas-plot-histogram-of-dates)

Comment: That's similar, but it uses equal spacing. I found a very similar answer, but it uses a line graph, not a histogram http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3486121/how-to-plot-data-against-specific-dates-on-the-x-axis-using-matplotlib?rq=1

Comment: if you change the `graph.plot(x,y,'r-o')` to `graph.bar(x,y)` in that answer, is that close to what you want?

Comment: Yup, that'll do it. Close enough. Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Histogram in matplotlib, time on x-Axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672375/histogram-in-matplotlib-time-on-x-axis)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51321575/simplest-histogram-with-dates-as-x-axis-in-matplotlib