# Simplest histogram with dates as x-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to properly display a simple histogram with dates as x-axis and integers as y-axis. The example below happens to be a subplot (2 y-axis, 1 shared x-axis) but the problem is not there, it's rather the hist itself.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')   # server no need to display graphics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x-axis is 3 consecutive dates (days)
now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
x = [now, now + datetime.timedelta(days=1), now + datetime.timedelta(days=2)]

# y1-axis is 3 numbers
y1 = [10, 0, 3]
y2 = [8, 0, 3]

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
bins = range(1, len(x) + 1)
axarr[1].hist(y1, bins=len(x), edgecolor="k")
axarr[1].set_xticks(bins)
axarr[1].set_xticklabels(x)
axarr[1].set_yticks(range(0, max(y1) + 1))

# axarr[0] ommitted for simplicity

plt.savefig('a.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

However the image I get is ...

[image]

Comment: Have you checked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083051/matplotlib-xticks-not-lining-up-with-histogram ?

Comment: @Georgy Thank you, but finally it was a blunder of mine, I needed a `bar` graph instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a `bar` graph.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')   # server no need to display graphics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# x-axis is 3 consecutive dates (days)
now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
x = [now, now + datetime.timedelta(days=1), now + datetime.timedelta(days=2)]

# y1-axis is 3 numbers
y1 = [10, 0, 3]
y2 = [8, 0, 3]

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True)
axarr[1].bar(x, y1, edgecolor="k")
axarr[1].set_xticks(x)
axarr[1].set_xticklabels(x)

plt.savefig('a.png', bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image]

Comment: `bins` seems to be a leftover from the original code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want dates on the x axis of your histogram, it is the dates that need to be the argument to `hist`.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().date()
x = [now, now + datetime.timedelta(days=1), now + datetime.timedelta(days=2)]

axarr[1].hist(x, edgecolor="k")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's correct, you don't define y-values to histograms... That's why I need a `bar` graph apparently :S

Comment: +1. This answer addresses the title (Google led me here). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29672375/histogram-in-matplotlib-time-on-x-axis